# Checking truthiness of user.name@domain.com - regular expressions

Tags: regex

I'd like to check for truthiness in character strings.

I'd like to ensure a string is of the form firstname.lastname@domain.com.

Using grepl I'm able to confirm that "@domain.com" exists..

```
> string <- "bob.smith@domain.com"
> grepl("@domain.com", string)
# [1] TRUE
```

I'd like to also confirm that there are n characters to the left and right of the period. For example "bobsmith@domain.com" should return false because a period does not separate any strings before the "@". The `.` that separates the first and last name should only appear before the `@` and must have characters before and after.

Comment: Try `grepl("^\\S+\\.\\S+@domain\\.com$", string)`. It is not that clear what exactly you want: if a `.`  should be anywhere in the name then the `+`  should be replaced with `*`.

Comment: The `.` can be only appear before `@` and there are characters before and after the `.`

Comment: So, try `grepl("^\\S*\\.\\S*@domain\\.com$", string)` or, if the name can be empty, `grepl("^\\S*(?:\\.\\S*)?@domain\\.com$", string)`

Comment: Made an edit to my comment. The `.` can only appear after and before characters. Your first comment is what I needed because ".ss@domain.com" would be `FALSE`, which is the desired behavior. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
grepl("^\\S+\\.\\S+@domain\\.com$", string)
```

The pattern will match

- `^` - start of string
- `\\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `\\.` - a dot
- `\\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `@domain\\.com` - `@domain.com` substring
- `$` - end of string.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NZBKjf/1).

Note: If there is only 1 dot allowed in the user name, replace `\S` with `[^\s.]` negated character class that matches any char but whitespace and a dot:

```
grepl("^[^\\s.]+\\.[^\\s.]+@domain\\.com$", string, perl=TRUE) ## or
grepl("^[^[:space:].]+\\.[^[:space:].]+@domain\\.com$", string)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NZBKjf/2).

Comment: > `grepl("^[^\\s.]+\\.[^\\s.]+@domain\\.com$", "user.name@domain.com")` is `FALSE`, which is not expected.

Comment: However using the same regex with `string = "abc.def@domain.com"` is `TRUE` .... very confusing.

Comment: If `"abc.def@domain.com"` is equal to `TRUE` why is `"user.name@domain.com"` equal to `FALSE`?

Comment: Sorry, you need to change that one. I updated the answer. TRE regex engine does not allow escape regex sequences in bracket expressions. Only POSIX character classes can be used, like `[:space:]`.